# Allow users to upload image and display them in html (using base64 and python)

Tags: python, html, sqlite, base64

I am new to web development and have been trying to allow many users to upload image and then it will display on the homepage. Currently using python and sqlite for the database and I'm not sure how I should encode the image into base64 and store it in my database before displaying the image on html. What's the easiest way to do so?
(the image is stored in request.form['photo'])

Comment: Ideally, don't store your images in the database.  But if you do, skip the base64 encoding and use straight binary.  Otherwise you're needlessly adding significant storage, memory, and CPU requirements.

Comment: but it seems like i cannot display the image in html that were stored in binary

Comment: Why not?  Your Python server can take a request for the image data.  In your HTML, `<img src="https://example.com/your-python-script" />`

Comment: hmmm..so if i save my photo as BLOB in my sqlite data base, may I know how i can obtain the link for that image?

Comment: The URL for that image will be whatever URL your Python script reveals.  As I show in that example, the browser just makes an HTTP request to your Python script, and your Python script then returns the binary image data.

Comment: hi, im so sorry but how do you obtain the url from a form? i'm using flask forms

Comment: how do i make a HTTP request to my python script?